# rails 3.2 code not working when fetched from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github, coffeescript

I am facing a problem when i fetched the rails project from github.

When i cloned the repository and try to run the code from a remote system, i got the following errors.

```
["ok","(function() {\n\n\n\n}).call(this);\n"]

(in e:/github_projects/myfork/TestRepo/TestProj/app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee)
```

Extracted source (around line #6):

```
3: <head>
4:   <title>TestProj</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
```

I am currently using rails 3.2.0 in windows environment.

I have created only a simple rails project with user scaffold in order to test it.

Its working fine while i worked with that in my local system before moving to github.

Thanks,

Mani

Comment: would you please paste the content of users.js.coffee?

Comment: I do not have any content in that file other than the default content produced while performing scaffold. The default content is as given below.                                                       # Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

Answer (score 1):

It's quite strange, I might recommend that you delete everything in the user.js.coffee and save it and try again. It looks that there's some wrong returns in there.

Comment: I got narrowed down this issue now. It might be mainly due to my  windows 7 system. i am freshly trying to install the rails to check out this issue. Now its causing another problem which i am trying to resolve using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780756/cannot-install-json-gem-in-rails-using-windows