# rails new project error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just wondering if anyone experienced this been looking around online to fix it, haven't stumbled across anything just yet.

Installing json (1.7.6) with native extensions Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension .

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9 .1/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection. Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7. 6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out An error occured while installing json (1.7.6), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that gem install json -v '1.7.6' succeeds before bundling.

Comment: looks like it is a Windows JSON issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780756

Answer (score 0):

You need the Ruby DevKit witch provides the compiler to create the gem. You can get it here:

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/