# what cause ruby invalid option -1 (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

im new to ruby. i tried to run [this](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io) repository on local, i have done all the necessary requirement (installed ruby-dev, bundler) but always get an error when running `'bundle exec jekyll liveserve'` the error `'invalid option -1 (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)'`

i tried to re-install it, clear the bundle but the error still there, can someone tell me where i did wrong?

Comment: I tried running the application myself, and ran into a couple of different issues. It seems it hasn't been updated in a long time, and might not work correctly across all ruby versions/operating systems.

Comment: Here's what I did to fix it (MacOS, ruby 3.1.2): (1) Add `gem 'webrick'` to the Gemfile. (2) Add `gem 'jekyll', '< 3.9.2'` to the Gemfile.

Comment: The latter issue is reported [here](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/issues/943), which is where I found the fix.

Comment: i tried using jekyll 3.9.2 and 3.9.3 it seems doesnt fix the issue, the error remain the same ```C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\ruby.exe: invalid option -1  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)```

Comment: `< 3.9.2` means "LESS THAN" 3.9.2. The linked issue reports a bug introduced by version 3.9.2.

Comment: And is there no further information in the backtrace about where this mysterious `-1` error is coming from? Another possible fix from googling: `unset RUBYOPT`? https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/issues/154#issuecomment-582469166

Comment: the initial gemfile is using 3.9.0, tried to upgrade it to 3.9.2 and 3.9.3 seems didnt solve the issue

Comment: and thats excatly why im asking, what does this -1 error come from i have no idea

Comment: "the initial gemfile is using 3.9.0" -- No, it's not. [The `Gemfile`](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io/blob/master/Gemfile) doesn't even specify a version of `jekyll`, and there's no `Gemfile.lock` checked in to the repository. But by default [it's pulling the latest version of `github-pages`, which depends on `jekyll` version `3.9.3`](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/07c850988cd9d957b08203b52c24085b97c12516/lib/github-pages/dependencies.rb#L10). But by specifying version `3.9.0` in the `Gemfile`, you can force it to use dependencies compatible with that version

Comment: *"what does this -1 error come from i have no idea"* -- I also don't know, and I'm at the disadvantage of not having access to your machine to debug further ... I gave a couple of possible causes based on some Google searches, but without seeing any more backtrace information I'm quite restricted in what to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, the closest solution I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16498438/1954610). The problem *might* be that:

- You're still using ruby version 1.9.3 (even though it [reached End Of Life **8 years ago**](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/01/10/ruby-1-9-3-will-end-on-2015/))
- The path to your ruby installation contains spaces, e.g. `C:/Ruby/Ruby 1.9.3/`

To fix the problem, try removing spaces from the ruby installation path. Additionally, I'd strongly recommend using a more modern version of ruby (`v3.0+`; ideally the latest - which is currently `3.2.2`).

Comment: hey tom thank you for the advice, but i did use the newer version of ruby which is Ruby3.2.2 and for the folder name, the default when im doing the installation are Ruby32-x64 so i think it might not be the issue