# How to install json 1.8.0 on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rake, redmine

Let me explain the context first, I want to create a server for Redmine. While following the steps of this site: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI_on_Windows_with_Apache, I was confronted to the step of running this command

```
rake generate_session_store
```

which gave me this error when trying to run it:

```
Could not find gem 'rails (=3.2.13) x86-ming32' in the gems available on this machine
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems
```

when I checked my gem list, only rails (2.3.5) is installed
so i tried *bundle install*

which gave me this error:

```
[...] Failed to build gem native extension.[...]

Creating Makefile

make

'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Gem files will remain installed in [C:/webserver......]
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 'gem install json -v '1.8.0' succeeds before bundling.
```

So I tried `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` and got the same error.

I finally tried `gem install rails(=3.2.13) x86 -ming32` and got the 2 errors:

```
Could not find a valid gem '(=3.2.13)'(>=0) in any repository

Could not find a valid gem 'x86 -ming32' (>=0) in any repository
```

I am now very confused in all of these errors, and I don't know much of the `gem` tool... I've seen many questions asked on json (especially on Mac, but I am on Windows) but never on that particular error. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780756/cannot-install-json-gem-in-rails-using-windows

Comment: I have seen that question before writing mine, but it is clearly not the same issue that we are having!! The error is completely different!

Comment: Different error but both are related to building native gems an Windows. Do you have the development kit installed?

Comment: have you tried to install the ruby development kit which brings a lot of tools needed for installing some gems properly? such as 'make' which can automaticly run builds on your system as defined by a makefile https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit

Comment: installing json can be a pain in non-Unix env(if you don't have sufficient tools), try json_pure(same func but written in ruby so no native extension....).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with json and Windows environment.

I've installed Cygwin (http://cygwin.com/install.html) and selected all main mingw libraries (at the last step of the installation process).

Running "gem install -v '1.8.0'" now works.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem but I solved it by following these instruction:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Only thing to note is I had the 64-bit version on ruby so I needed the 64-bit version of the DevKit