# Installing any gems in ruby will bring ERROR: failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, makefile, rubygems

I am using windows 8.1 with Ruby 1.9.3 - when I try to install any gems this error shows:

```
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141011-6892-1pldhkg.rb extconf.rb

checking for ffi.h... no

checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no

checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes

checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes

checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes

checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... no

creating extconf.h

creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.6
for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/ff
i-1.9.6/gem_make.out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot install JSON gem in rails using windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780756/cannot-install-json-gem-in-rails-using-windows)

Comment: the answer from that question suggests that I install DevKit - I forgot to mention that I already had it installed when the problem occured

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by reinstalling Ruby (1.9.3) and making sure to check the "Add Ruby executables to your PATH" checkbox during installation.

Source: the first section of this page https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting