# Could not find gem 'wdm (>= 0.1.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm loosing my mind trying to figure out how to solve this issue. I don't know anything about Ruby, I'm just trying to read the docs of react which needs Jekyll to serve them as they're markdowns (didn't understand why they need to complicate things like that). The readme file of the docs says that you have to install these:

- [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/) (version >= 1.8.7)
- [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) (version >= 1.3.7)
- [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/)

which I've done. And then you'll have to do these instructions:

- cd react/docs
- bundle exec rake
- bundle exec jekyll serve -w
- open http://localhost:4000/react/index.html

But when I execute the second command `bundle exec rake`, this stupid error is thrown:

> Could not find gem 'wdm (>= 0.1.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I run `bundle install` and it throw an error too:

> An error occurred while installing json (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.

I try to install `gem install json -v '2.0.1'` and it throws an error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing json:
>
> ```
>    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> ```

What the hell is going on? Why don't they make something simple? This should be easy not as complicated as rocket science!

**Note:** I'm using Windows 32bit if that is of some importance.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: try `gem install wdm -v=0.1.1` before running `bundle install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the DevKit. Learn how [**here**](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)!

Then make sure bundle is installed or install it like this:

```
gem install bundle
```

Comment: I installed it using `gem install bundle`. But didn't do it in the docs directory, should I install it there as well? I'm not familliar with how gems get installed, do they get installed globally (accessed from anywhere) or one must install them locally for each directory?

Comment: You're trying to run [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/) right?
I missed the 2nd part that says you were having trouble with JSON. Can you paste the error into your question? That will be relevant.

Comment: I added the error! It's a big error! I think that bit of it is the important one!

Comment: No it throwed the same error as when I was installing JSON (the error I've just posted)!

Comment: Wondering if this might be related:
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3208#issuecomment-67107338

Comment: And that led me to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780756/cannot-install-json-gem-in-rails-using-windows
Perhaps it might help.